# More informative "cabal update"

Tags: haskell

I run `cabal update` from time to time but each time there is no results printed.

Is there anyway to see what have been updated after running the  command ?

Answer (score 2):

`cabal update --help` suggests a `--verbose` flag.  Does that help?

You can also control the verbosity level. Default is 1 but you can give anything between 0 to 3.

Example: `cabal update --verbose=3`